# Laravel: retrieve bound model from request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there any easy way of retrieving the route binded model within a Request?

I want to update a model, but before I do, I want to perform some permissions checks using the Requests `authorize()` method. But I only want the owner of the model to be able to update it.

In the controller, I would simply do something like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Booking $booking)
{
    if($booking->owner->user_id === Auth::user()->user_id)
    {
       // Continue to update
    }
}
```

But I'm looking to do this within the Request, rather than within the controller. If I do:

```
dd(Illuminate\Http\Request::all());
```

It only gives me the scalar form properties (such as `_method` and so on, but not the model).

**Question**

If I bind a model to a route, how can I retrieve that model from within a Request?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As an update to this question: you may want to check out Laravel’s [authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization) component. Seems perfect for your needs!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Absolutely! It’s an approach I even use myself.

You can get the current route in the request, and then any parameters, like so:

```php
class UpdateRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        // Get bound Booking model from route
        $booking = $this->route('booking');

        // Check owner is the currently authenticated user
        return $booking->owner->is($this->user());
    }
}
```

Unlike [smartman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775032/laravel-retrieve-binded-model-in-request/#29775225)’s (now deleted) answer, this doesn’t incur another find query if you have already retrieved the model via route–model binding.

However, I’d also personally use a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies) here instead of putting authorisation checks in form requests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I knew it was probably going to be something simple like that but couldn't work it out myself! I'll accept when it allows me to :)

Comment: wow, didn't know about this Laravel feature! Learn something new every day! :)

Comment: If I understood correctly getting the route parameter laravel automatically understands which instance this parameter is binded to?

Comment: @akad0 If you have a route defined like this: `Route::get('bookings/{booking}');`, then fetching the `booking` parameter would yield the value of whatever’s bound to the `{booking}` token.

Comment: @MartinBean Just the value or the whole instance? Looking at your code you are using `$booking` as an instance and accessing it's related function `owner()` to retrieve the `user_id` attribute.
EDIT: Or you are just passing the instance as the value?

Comment: @akad0 All I’m doing is assigning the value of something to a variable. If you use [route–model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding), then route parameters will be model instances rather than IDs.

Comment: @MartinBean Yeah, you are right I edit my question but you were to fast :P. Thanks for the explanation, it was really useful

Comment: Does `route('param')` work in L5.3 to retrieve the bound model? For some reason it is giving me just the route slug upon updating my app to L5.3.. It was working fine in L5.2

Comment: I'm using Laravel  5.4 and it's not working for me my route is defined like this `Route::resource('activity','ActivityController');` and  inside the `authorize()`method I only have `return Gate::allows('update-activity', $this->route('activity'));`. And it's not binding the model but the integer value of the `activity` id.

Comment: @JuanMenéndezBuitrago I think it’ll be because you haven’t type-hinted `Activity` in your controller action.

Answer (score 4):

Once you did your explicit binding (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) you actually can get your model directly with $this.

```
class UpdateRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return $this->booking->owner->user_id == $this->booking->user()->id;
    }
}
```

Even cleaner!

Answer (score 2):

To add on to [Martin Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775232/174620)'s answer, you can access the bound instance using just `route($param)`:

```
class UpdateRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        $booking = $this->route('booking');

        return $booking->owner->user_id == $this->user()->id;
    }
}
```

***Note:*** This works in Laravel 5.1. I have not tested this on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `bindings` middleware or if you want to access the bound `$model` anywhere else apart from `FormRequest` and `Controller` you can use the following:

```
$book = app(Book::class)->resolveRouteBinding(request()->route('book'));
```